# Center a View on the top of another

Tags: android, android-layout

Using this image for reference, I have my red View. At some point on my RelativeLayout.

I want the left side of the Blue to match the left side of the Red

I want the center of the Blue to match the top of the Red

The Red can be any size, so I want it to be relative. I just can't figure it out!

I'm actually doing this in code, but for purposes of an example here's a starting point:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"
    android:background="#ffff0000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/red"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/red"
    android:background="#990000ff" />
```

Gives this

[image]

I'm looking to make this (I set a margin in dp here, but I can't do that -- I won't know the dimensions of the red or blue views at run time). Red and blue are not necessarily the same size.

[image]

Comment: Can we see your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

```
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
```

will work hopefully. For example

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Red Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="154dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Blue Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually comes out like this:

http://i.imgur.com/tAtSHik.png

What I'm after is this (I just dragged it here to set a margin, I can't do this because I don't know the dimensions beforehand)

http://i.imgur.com/JWVicQ3.png

Comment: Actually you should not be aware of any parameter. Just add the last 2 lines in your 2nd button (the blue one for your case) `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"` and `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"`
rest of the thing will be adjusted in the run time..

Comment: Copy/pasting your code into the XML shows this, which isn't quite what I'm after. http://i.imgur.com/tAtSHik.png I've modified the original question to be a bit clearer :)

Comment: okay I think I can give you a tricky solution. Just for clarification, tell me one thing, are the hight of the both buttons same or it could be different?

Comment: They are different, and I they change at run-time